# Keeping a SVN branch up to date with the main trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, branching-and-merging, trunk

I have branched from the trunk few days ago at which point i had an identical copy. I have made some modifications on couple of the files.

The main trunk has had some changes which I want to merge into my branch (so that i am up to date with the trunk). So using Tortoise SVN when i do a Test Merge, there doesn't seem to be any conflicts, only additions/deletions and modifications.

The question is, how is this possible?

My solution is:
1. In the branch create a patch using Tortoise SVN and save the file.
2. Revert changes in the branch
3. Merge from Trunk into branch
4. Apply patch in the branch

Haven't really tried, this but am going to now.

If anyone has come across this situation and found a solution please let me know, and also if you think my solution will or will not work.

Thanks.

Comment: If TortoiseSVN tells you that there is no conflict, then there's no conflict, and you should be happy. Why do you want to revert and patch instead of just merging, since it works, and doesn't even cause any conflict? Do you lime making things difficult when they're easy?

Comment: If I do the merge, then my changes + trunk changes are all together. So its not easy to see my changes as easy as checking for modifications. And I actually am trying to make it easy for myself, so that all I have to do when im working on my working copy is to check for modifications and I can see my changes.

Comment: Make a first commit with your changes. Then merge from trunk and make a second commit with the commit message "merge from trunk". When viewing the logs, it's easy to see which commits are changes, and which commits are merges.

Comment: Okay, I guess this is the alternative, and probably the general thing which everyone does in this instance. I probably will try and get used to that, or maybe use my solution (it seems to work, not sure in the case of conflicts), thanks

Comment: The main thing is the fact that, when I want to see the changes which I made on the branch, I have to open up the Browser, and mark the Trunk and the Branch for comparison. Rather then if i had the local changes it would be as simple as Check for modifications.

Comment: You don't need to mark the trunk and the branch for comparison. You just have to select a particular commit in the branch and see what changes it contains. SVN also serves as a "backup" tool: each time you have something that compiles and adds something, you should commit it. If you stay for days with local modifications without committing, not only is collaboration much harder, but you risk losing all your changes if you do a mistake.